# how to keep adding the values when checkbox is checked?

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, checkbox, switch-statement

When i check all the checkboxes the total still ends up being 10. I don't know what is going on here please help

```
Dim top As Integer
    Select Case top
        Case CheckBox1.Checked
            top = +10
        Case CheckBox2.Checked
            top = +10
        Case CheckBox3.Checked
            top = +10
        Case CheckBox4.Checked
            top = +10
        Case CheckBox5.Checked
            top = +10
        Case CheckBox6.Checked
            top = +10
    End Select
    TextBox2.Text = top
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a sensible `Select Case` statement. You should be using multiple `If` statements.

Comment: You are testing the `top` variable that doesn't have any value....btw, I didn't downvote your question :)

Comment: Not a full answer obviously, but `top = +10` is the same as `top = 10` whereas you want `top += 10`

Answer (score 2):

A `select case` statement is like an `if...else if` statement.
This means that once one of the cases is true, no other cases will be executed even if they are true.
Change your code to something like this instead:

```
If CheckBox1.Checked Then 
    top += 10
End If
If CheckBox2.Checked Then 
    top += 10
End If
If CheckBox3.Checked Then 
    top += 10
End If
....
```